# View only partially refreshed after $scope.$on()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this AngularJS controller for a pre-filled form, fetching the data is triggered by an event using $broadcast and $on. However, when the data updates, only some of the corresponding fields get updated in the view.

```
$scope.currentHouse = {};
$scope.$on('houseInfoLoad', function(event, data) {

    $scope.currentHouse = data.houseDetail; //does not refresh the view
    console.log($scope.currentHouse); //output is correct
    
    //the next three calls refresh the corresponding fields in the view
    $scope.changeGarageRadioValue($scope.currentHouse.hasGarage);
    utils.setSelection($scope.houseKeywords, $scope.currentHouse.keyword.id);
    utils.setSelection($scope.houseTypes, $scope.currentHouse.type.id);     
    
});
```

`changeGarageRadioValue()` essentially does what it says, and `utils.setSelection(list, id)` adds a `selected = true` property to the element of the list that has the id. This has the effect of setting the value of a select field (using isteven's [multi-select plugin](https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select)).

The view has a few text fields bound to properties of `$scope.currentHouse`, as well as these radio buttons and select fields.

The result is that the text fields sometimes **do not** get updated, however the select and radio buttons **do**.

Here's what I tried unsuccessfully:

- Wrapping everything in a `$timeout()`;
- Calling `$scope.$apply()` after setting `$scope.currentHouse` (throws an error saying that we are already inside an `$apply()`)
- Changing the initial definition of $scope.currentHouse from `{}` to an object with each of the fields set to null.

Can anyone see what I am missing, or how to force trigger the refresh?

**EDIT** : with extracts from the view :

A text field:

```
<label>ADDITIONAL DESCRIPTION</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="currentHouse.additionalDescription" class="input-mandatory" value=""/>
</div>
```

A multi-select:

```
<label>TYPE</label>
<div>
    <div directive-id="houseType" multi-select input-model="houseTypes" output-model="currentHouse.type" button-label="text" item-label="text" selection-mode="single" default-label="Select" tick-property="selected" ></div>
</div>
```

The radio buttons :

```
<div><label>HAS GARAGE</label></div>
<div>
    <div id="radiobuttonNo" ng-click="changeGarageRadioValue(false);">
        NO
    </div>
    <div id="radiobuttonYes" ng-click="changeGarageRadioValue(true);" class="active">
        YES
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT #2** as per Alok Singh's suggestion:

I tried putting `data.houseDetail` into `$scope.currentHouse.house` instead of `$scope.currentHouse` directly, and changing the view accordingly. Still no results.

Comment: Could you show us your view code?

Comment: I have added extracts from it. The actual view is a bit more complex, it is a modal window so the controller and view are called from a parent view.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.currentHouse = data.houseDetail
```

You cannot get the updated value of `currentHouse` because its a model.
So change the above code i.e

```
$scope.currentHouse.house = data.houseDetail
```

Comment: Trying this right now, it's not working right away but it's giving me funny results. I'll keep you posted, thanks.

Comment: Still the same results unfortunately. I'll update my question to mention I tried this.